# EFCore - Soft deleted entity still appears in next get query

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have implemented soft delete feature in my .net 5 web api with EfCore using global entity framework feature and then update the `IsDeleted` flag as below:

```
private void UpdateAuditableProperties()
{
  foreach (EntityEntry entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries()) {
    switch (entityEntry.State) {
      case EntityState.Deleted:
        ManageDeletedEntity(entityEntry);
        break;
      ... Other methods
    }
  }
}

private void ManageDeletedEntity(EntityEntry entityEntry)
{
  if(entityEntry.Entity is AuditableEntity) {
    entityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    entityEntry.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
  }
}
```

Both `Get` and `Delete` api works fine when executed individually.
I have a use case where I am deleting child entity and want to update the parent total based on that in the same execution.

```
  _repository.Delete(entity);
  await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
  await _parentService.Update(entity.ParentId);
```

But there when I select parent with all child entities, the deleted entity still shows up with `IsDeleted` as `true`.

I am not able to figure out why the query is not applying the filter in this case even though I am saving the context before updating the parent.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` after `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It is working but I am not entirely sure about the behavior. Once the changes are committed, shouldn't the change tracker clear by default. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No. it keeps loaded objects. In your case soft deleted.